# Drag-and-drop from IE 9 into my application

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, user-interface, drag-and-drop

It's kind of weird issue, let me try to explain. I wrote a (dialog based) app in c++/MFC that supports drag-n-dropping.

I do the following test on Windows 7 with default themes. My app is running on the screen. It is not a top window (in its z-order) or in other words it's obscured by other windows on top of it.

If I begin dragging a link or just a text selection from the Chrome or Firefox web browser, first into my app's icon on the taskbar, the icon flashes and my app pops up on the screen (by receiving the top z-order) so I can then drag-and-drop into my app. Everything works fine.

If I do the same from IE 9 (version 9.0.8112, update versions 9.0.12) when I drag selected text or a link first to the taskbar icon of my app to make my app become top window (in z-order), the app icon continues flashing but it never gets shown on the screen like it happens with Chrome or FF, so as a result I have to abandon my drag-and-drop.

Any idea why is it happening like that with IE and if there's a way to fix it?

**EDIT:** Here's the code sample in regards to my comments below:

```
HRESULT __stdcall DragEnter(IDataObject* pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD* pdwEffect)
{
    //IDropTarget::DragEnter
    m_fAllowDrop = QueryDataObject(pDataObject);

    if(m_fAllowDrop)
    {
        //SUCCESS
        // get the dropeffect based on keyboard state
    }
    else
    {
        //FAILURE
        *pdwEffect = DROPEFFECT_NONE;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

BOOL QueryDataObject(IDataObject* pDataObject, int* pnOutDataType)
{
    static FORMATETC fmtetc_file = {CF_HDROP, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
    static FORMATETC fmtetc_txt = {CF_UNICODETEXT, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};

    BOOL bRes = FALSE;
    HRESULT hr;

    //See if our data type
    hr = pDataObject->QueryGetData(&fmtetc_file);
    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        bRes = TRUE;
    }

    //In my case hr is E_FAIL or 0x80004005

    hr = pDataObject->QueryGetData(&fmtetc_txt);
    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        bRes = TRUE;
    }

    //In my case hr is E_FAIL or 0x80004005

    return bRes;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As part of its sandboxing to prevent unauthorized changes to the machine, Internet Explorer runs in a lower UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation) integrity level than other apps do.  As such, it does not have permission to access your app by default, which is more likely to be running in a medium or high UIPI integrity level (depending on whether it is UAC elevated or not).  The flashing taskbar button means that something is trying to bring your app to the foreground but does not have permission to do so (see the documentation of [`SetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539.aspx) for more details).  UIPI does not allow a lower-integrity process to send window messages to a higher-integrity process unless the receiving process explicitally tells UIPI to allow it.  Chrome and FireFox are likely running in the same integrity level as your app.  In order to support drag-and-drop from Internet Explorer, call [`ChangeWindowMessageFilter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675.aspx) or [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202.aspx) to let your app receive `WM_DROPFILES`, `WM_COPYDATA`, and `WM_COPYGLOBALDATA` (0x0049) messages from lower-integrity processes.

**Update:** It looks like Internet Explorer in particular imposes additional restrictions on drag&drop operations when it is running in Protected Mode:

[How to handle drag & drop from low integrity Internet Explorer](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/how-handle-drag-drop-low-integrity-internet-explorer-help-187625691.html)

[Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer - Allowing Drag and Drop Operations in your Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462.aspx#wpm_addya)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can now drag files into my app, although the "drop" part doesn't seem to work. For some reason `IDataObject::QueryGetData` that is called from processing `QueryDataObject` returns `0x80004005` or `E_FAIL` when I drag text from IE.

Comment: Are you querying a data format that the `IDataObject` actually supports?

Comment: I updated my original post with the code. If you look at the `QueryDataObject` method, the `HRESULT` I get in both cases for `CF_HDROP` and `CF_UNICODETEXT` is `E_FAIL`. I don't know why? PS. Note that the code above works with Chrome and FF. PS2. FYI, I am dragging a text selection.

Comment: Have you tried `CF_TEXT` and `CFSTR_INETURL` yet? Have you tried using other `TYMED` values besides just `TYMED_HGLOBAL`? Have you tried using `IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc()` to find out what format(s) are actually available in the `IDataObject` and usable with `QueryGetData()`? Just because something works with Chrome/FF does not guarantee that it works with IE. They are separate apps, afterall. They do not have to use the exact same formats.

Comment: I just tried `CF_TEXT` and it didn't work either. I then tried to enumerate formats that I get from IE by calling `IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc()` and it returned the exact same struct as my `{CF_UNICODETEXT, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL}` -- 1-to-1, but still `QueryGetData` returned `E_FAIL` right after that. What is also annoying is that the docs for `QueryGetData` have no mentioning of `E_FAIL`.

Comment: I just did a small test. I ran IE and my app elevated and then drag-and-drop worked just fine. So there's still something with this UIPI that is not covered by those 3 messages you suggested. Is there something with COM that needs to done too?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `IDataObject::GetData()`? Clearly COM itself is working since `IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc()` is working.

Comment: I get `E_FAIL` from `IDataObject::GetData()` as well. No, COM itself is working, but there might be some security flag or privilege mask that has not been adjusted to accounted for the UIPI. Also how did you come up with those Windows messages that you suggested? I tried running my app through Spy++ to see what's going on but I couldn't see what other messages are blocked.

Comment: If `EnumFormatEtc()` is working then there is no reason for `Query/GetData()` to fail, unless IE is encountering an internal bug when accessing the data in memory. As for how I know which messages to allow through UIPI, that info is readily available online, as implementing drag&drop through UAC/UIPI is a commonly encountered problem (I encountered it in onw of my own apps awhile back ago). Spy++ cannot show you blocked messages.

Comment: I compiled a test MFC (VS 2008) project to illustrate the issue. Can you take a look? http://forums.codeguru.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=30901&d=1359009283

Comment: The only issues I see are that `CMyDropTarget::RegisterDragDropWnd()` has a memory leak if it returns FALSE, `CMyDropTarget::DropData()` is calling `IDataObject::QueryGetData()` when it does not need to, and `CMyDropTarget::DropData()` is casting the dropped text to `TCHAR*` when it is really `WCHAR*` instead. But nothing that would explain the `IDataObject` failures.

Comment: Something I just found: [How to handle drag & drop from low integrity Internet Explorer](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/how-handle-drag-drop-low-integrity-internet-explorer-help-187625691.html).

Comment: Thanks for finding the memory leak in my code and for pointing out that article. Wow! Registering for drag-and-drop in the HKLM key! Who in their sane mind could've come up with such an idiocy? I'm not going to explore it any further because I can't change anything in the HKLM key from my app... Why don't you update your original post and I'll mark it as an answer. This find may be helpful for others.

Comment: You could create an installer for you app, and have the installer run with admin rights, then it can access HKLM and register your main app.

Comment: True. Or... I can stop using IE and suggest others to do the same :) Thanks for your help!